# Pass "preference variable" between activites, set value in original activity

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to allow users to enter the bluetooth address of their module as text.

Pressing <kbd>Menu</kbd> in activity 1 (`MainActivity.java`) brings up an option menu. Choosing <kbd>Settings</kbd> switches to activity 2 (`SetPreferences.java`). Entering the MAC address in the text box and pressing <kbd>Apply</kbd> resumes activity 1, with no change in the value of address.

Any help would be much appreciated guys!

Begin Code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.showstopperled.defiance;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.showstopperled.defiance.ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnColorChangedListener {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "DefiancePrefsFile";
    static String Packet = null;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private static OutputStream outStream = null;

    SeekBar seekbarUnicorns, seekbarChan, seekbarRed, seekbarGreen,
            seekbarBlue, seekbarBand, seekbarSens;
    TextView valueUnicorns, valueChan, valueRed, valueGreen, valueBlue,
            valueBand, valueSens, valueSave;
    static int Channel = 0;
    static int Rset = 255;
    static int Gset = 0;
    static int Bset = 0;
    static int Mode = 0;
    static int Band = 0;
    static int Sens = 24;
    static int Save = 0;
    static int Unicorns = 0;

    String audB = "63Hz";

    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // hardcoded MAC address
    static String address = null;
    private BufferedReader buf;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        valueChan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewChan);
        seekbarChan = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarChan);
        valueRed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRed);
        seekbarRed = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarRed);
        valueGreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGreen);
        seekbarGreen = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarGreen);
        valueBlue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBlue);
        seekbarBlue = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarBlue);
        valueBand = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBand);
        seekbarBand = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarBand);
        valueSens = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSens);
        seekbarSens = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSens);
        valueUnicorns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUnicorns);
        seekbarUnicorns = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarUnicorns);

        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMode);
        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int i,
                    long lng) {
                Mode = i;
                packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns,
                        Save);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // do something else
            }
        });

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Please enable your BT and re-run this program.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        int sbar_chan_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_chan_pref", 0);
        seekbarChan.setProgress(sbar_chan_position);
        valueChan.setText("Channel: " + sbar_chan_position);
        Channel = sbar_chan_position;

        int sbar_red_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_red_pref", 0);
        seekbarRed.setProgress(sbar_red_position);
        valueRed.setText("Red: " + sbar_red_position);
        Rset = sbar_red_position;

        int sbar_green_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_green_pref", 0);
        seekbarGreen.setProgress(sbar_green_position);
        valueGreen.setText("Green: " + sbar_green_position);
        Gset = sbar_green_position;

        int sbar_blue_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_blue_pref", 0);
        seekbarBlue.setProgress(sbar_blue_position);
        valueBlue.setText("Blue: " + sbar_blue_position);
        Bset = sbar_blue_position;

        int sbar_band_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_band_pref", 0);
        seekbarBand.setProgress(sbar_band_position);
        valueBand.setText("Band: " + sbar_band_position);
        Band = sbar_band_position;

        int sbar_sens_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_sens_pref", 0);
        seekbarSens.setProgress(sbar_sens_position);
        valueSens.setText("Sensitivity: " + sbar_sens_position);
        Sens = sbar_sens_position;

        int sbar_unicorns_position = settings
                .getInt("seekbar_unicorns_pref", 0);
        seekbarUnicorns.setProgress(sbar_unicorns_position);
        valueUnicorns.setText("Unicorns!: " + sbar_unicorns_position);
        Unicorns = sbar_unicorns_position;

        seekbarChan.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueChan.setText("Channel: " + (progress + 1));
                Channel = progress;
                packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns,
                        Save);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        seekbarRed.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueRed.setText("Red: " + progress);

                Rset = progress;
                packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns,
                        Save);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        seekbarGreen.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueGreen.setText("Green: " + progress);

                Gset = progress;
                packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns,
                        Save);

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        seekbarBlue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueBlue.setText("Blue: " + progress);

                Bset = progress;
                packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns,
                        Save);

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        seekbarBand.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                switch (progress) {
                case 0:
                    audB = "63Hz";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    audB = "160Hz";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    audB = "400Hz";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    audB = "1kHz";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    audB = "2.5kHz";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    audB = "6.25kHz";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    audB = "16kHz";
                    break;
                }
                valueBand.setText("Band: " + audB);

                Band = progress;
                packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns,
                        Save);

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        seekbarSens.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueSens.setText("Sensitivity: " + (progress + 1));

                Sens = progress;
                packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns,
                        Save);

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        seekbarUnicorns
                .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                            int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        valueUnicorns.setText("Unicorns!: " + progress);

                        Unicorns = progress;
                        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens,
                                Unicorns, Save);

                    }

                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Settings");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "About");
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Help");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SetPreferences.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            address = intent.getExtras().getString("address");
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("address", address);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        case 1:
            // launch ABOUT here
            break;
        case 2:
            // Launch here
            break;
        default:
            // Launch SETTINGS here
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) {

        int sbar_red_position = Color.red(color);
        int sbar_green_position = Color.green(color);
        int sbar_blue_position = Color.blue(color);

        seekbarRed.setProgress(sbar_red_position);
        valueRed.setText("Red: " + sbar_red_position);
        Rset = sbar_red_position;

        seekbarGreen.setProgress(sbar_green_position);
        valueGreen.setText("Green: " + sbar_green_position);
        Gset = sbar_green_position;

        seekbarBlue.setProgress(sbar_blue_position);
        valueBlue.setText("Blue: " + sbar_blue_position);
        Bset = sbar_blue_position;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Defiance.txt");
            FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
            buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));
            String readString = new String();
            // just reading each line and pass it on the debugger
            while ((readString = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                address = readString;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // When this returns, it will 'know' about the server,
        // via it's MAC address.
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
        try {
            outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void onClickSave1(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 100;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickSave2(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 200;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickSave3(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 300;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickSave4(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 400;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickSave5(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 500;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickLoad1(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 10;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickLoad2(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 20;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickLoad3(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 30;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickLoad4(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 40;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickLoad5(View v) throws IOException {
        Save = 50;
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
        Save = 0;
    }

    public void onClickApply(View v) throws IOException {

        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("seekbar_red_pref", Rset);
        editor.putInt("seekbar_green_pref", Gset);
        editor.putInt("seekbar_blue_pref", Bset);
        editor.putString("address", address);
        editor.commit();

        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the Bluetooth chat services

    }

    public void onClickColorPicker(View v) {
        new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, Color.rgb(Rset, Gset, Bset)).show();
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
    }

    public void onClickRandomColor(View v) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int min = 0, max = 255;
        int randomRed = rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int randomGreen = rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int randomBlue = rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        Rset = randomRed;
        Gset = randomGreen;
        Bset = randomBlue;
        new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, Color.rgb(Rset, Gset, Bset)).show();
        packet(Channel, Rset, Gset, Bset, Mode, Band, Sens, Unicorns, Save);
    }

    public static void packet(int Channel, int Rset, int Gset, int Bset,
            int Mode, int Band, int Sens, int Unicorns, int Save) {
        int Rfin;
        int Gfin;
        int Bfin;
        int Sfin;
        int Ufin;
        Rfin = Rset * 16;
        Rfin = 4095 - Rfin;
        Gfin = Gset * 16;
        Gfin = 4095 - Gfin;
        Bfin = Bset * 16;
        Bfin = 4095 - Bfin;
        Sfin = Sens * 32;
        Ufin = Unicorns * 10;
        Ufin = 1000 - Ufin;
        Packet = "<HMG:" + Channel + ":" + Rfin + ":" + Gfin + ":" + Bfin + ":"
                + Mode + ":" + Band + ":" + Sfin + ":" + Ufin + ":" + Save
                + ">";
        byte[] msgBuffer;
        msgBuffer = Packet.getBytes();
        try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

SetPreferences.java:

```
package com.showstopperled.defiance;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SetPreferences extends Activity {

    EditText editMac;
    TextView valueMac;
    String address;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "DefiancePrefsFile";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set_preferences);
        EditText MacAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMac);
        MacAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMac);
        address = MacAddress.getText().toString();
        valueMac = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMac);
    }

    public void onClickMac(View v) throws IOException {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("address", address);
        editor.commit();
        address = settings.getString("address", address);
        valueMac.setText("Mac Address: " + address);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("address", address);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing a startActivityForResult, then getting the intent's value after.

This won't work, for the following reasons:

1. startActivityForResult doesn't actually trigger until the method you're calling it in (or more specifically, the event running in the UI Thread Looper) returns.
2. To get an activity's result, you should be using [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29). This intent will have the value you want.

What you're doing is telling the Looper to start the activity when the method returns, then you're getting an extra out of your own intent, then returning and letting the activity start. When it returns, you're not checking its result.

Comment: Changing 
startActivityForResult(0, intent); to
onActivityResult(0, 1, intent);
Causes Immediate Force close, would you like the log?

Comment: No no, you're dispatching the result just fine, it's the receiving that's broken.

Override the onActivityResult method of your activity. Read the javadoc I linked to.